# Atribuir valor a propriedade de um objeto por uma lista de objetos

Tags: c#, web-service, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma lista de objetos: List. Bem, esse objeto tem três propriedades, digamos, cnpj, acao e novaacao. Fiz um linq ou lambda e me trouxe todos os resultados, digamos duas linhas. Faço um foreach no resultado da linq ou lambda e como agora eu atribuo a cada propriedade do meu objeto através da lista desse objeto? Assim:

```
List<pdv> lista = new List<pdv>();
var resultado = (from ...).ToList();

foreach(var r in resultado)
{
   lista.Add(r.cnpj);//ISSO DÁ ERRO
}
```

Dessa forma, eu mostro apenas um cnpj, sendo que há dois. Sempre o último. novo é do tipo PDV criado antes.

```
if (resultadoPdv.Count > 0 && resultadoAcao.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var r in resultadoPdv)
                {
                    novo.cnpj = r.Cnpj;
                    lista.Add(novo);
                }

                foreach (var r in resultadoAcao)
                {
                    novo.acao = r.acao;
                    novo.proximaAcao = r.proximaacao;
                    lista.Add(novo);
                }
            }

            return lista;
```

Nesse código, eu consigo ter dois registros, ou seja, a lista tem duas linhas, mas com o mesmo cnpj e eu tenho dois cnpj diferentes.

```
foreach (var r in resultadoAcao)
                {
                    novo.acao = r.acao;
                    novo.proximaAcao = r.proximaacao;
                }

                foreach (var r in resultadoPdv)
                {
                    novo.cnpj = r.Cnpj;
                    lista.Add(novo);
                }
```

Veja como fica o xml de retorno do web service

```
<ArrayOfPdvNovo xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/V99SuporteTecnicoContracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<PdvNovo>
<acao>Visita Técnica</acao>
<cnpj>03146478000112</cnpj>
<proximaAcao>Agendamento de Visita Técnica Parceiro</proximaAcao>
</PdvNovo>
<PdvNovo>
<acao>Visita Técnica</acao>
<cnpj>03146478000112</cnpj>
<proximaAcao>Agendamento de Visita Técnica Parceiro</proximaAcao>
</PdvNovo>
</ArrayOfPdvNovo>
```

Pela resposta do Harry, alterei e ficou assim:

```
PdvNovo novo = new PdvNovo();

            if (resultadoPdv.Count > 0 && resultadoAcao.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var r in resultadoAcao)
                {
                    novo.acao = r.acao;
                    novo.proximaAcao = r.proximaacao;
                    //lista.Add(novo);
                }

                foreach (var r in resultadoPdv)
                {
                    PdvNovo _cnpj = new PdvNovo();
                    _cnpj.cnpj = r.Cnpj;
                    _cnpj.acao = novo.acao;
                    _cnpj.proximaAcao = novo.proximaAcao;
                    lista.Add(_cnpj);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Estou perguntando isso, porque se eu retorno o tipo pdv e se eu tiver dois cnpj, ele só mostra um, o último, claro. E preciso que ele me liste todos os cnpj na questão.

Comment: Dá erro porque a List é tipada (pdv) e você ta passando texto, eu acho que isso você já sabe?

Comment: `novo` ta instanciado fora do for?

Comment: Sim, está usando a mesma instância! coloque dentro do for que ele criara para cada item da lista um instância diferente, por isso há repetição no seu arquivo. Olha no meu exemplo eu postei a solução!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assim:

```cs
List<pdv> lista = new List<pdv>();
var resultado = (from ...).ToList();

foreach(var r in resultado)
{
   pdv _item = new pdv(); // instancie dentro do for!
   _item.cnpj = r.cnpj; // da um enter aqui e vai colocando os outros campos ... 
   lista.Add(_item);
}
```